# Exception thrown and not caught in IE7 (jquery.signalR-0.5.1.js, line 22 character 9)

Tags: signalr

```
if (!window.JSON) {
        // no JSON!
        throw "SignalR: No JSON parser found. Please ensure json2.js is referenced before the SignalR.js file if you need to support clients without native JSON parsing support, e.g. IE<8.";
    }
```

My mvc 4 webpage use signalR Hub works fine in Firefox, IE8 and Chrome but it has problems in IE7, did anyone get the same problems?

Comment: This also happens in IE8+ if Quirks mode is enabled.

Answer (score 5):

From the SignalR FAQ https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq:

Why doesn't SignalR work in browser IE6/IE7?

SignalR requires a JSON parser and ability to send xhr requests (for long polling). If your browser has none, you'll need to include json2.js in your application (SignalR will throw an error telling your you need it as well). You can get it on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks dfowler for your quick response, I added and committed json2.js to my application. But we must wait until the application is deployed to test, the error occurs only in deployed website.

Comment: The strange is that json does not work after deployment of my mvc4 application. Despite of it work fine in my pc.